# Determine the indefinitely differentiable functions of the form $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Determine the indefinitely differentiable functions of the form 
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy$$

We have been proposed this problem in our real-analysis course. After playing around with this, I believe the form of the functions is:

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$$

Demonstration:
$$f(x+y)= \frac{(x+y)^2}{2}=\frac{x^2 + y^2 + 2xy}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+xy=f(x)+f(y)+xy$$

What does everyone think about that?

Comment: It's a good guess, but this doesn't show that **every** possible function satisfying the requirements is of this form

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Right I figured I was leaving something out. I would really like some guidance for a technique in how to go about this sort of problem, as we have others like it. I really haven't an idea how to go about the mathematics of it besides just thinking about it for a while and guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that $f$ is once differentiable, we take the partial derivative of both sides of the equation wrt $x$ to find
$$
f'(x + y) = f'(x) + y \tag{1}
$$
Plugging in $x = 0$ into this equation yields
$$
f'(y) = f'(0) + y.
$$
That is, $f'$ must have the form $f'(x) = x + C$, where $C = f'(0)$.  Moreover, for any choice of $C$, we find that $f'$ satisfies (1).

From there, we can deduce that
$$
f(x) = \frac 12 x^2 + Cx + D.
$$
To figure out that we must have $D = 0$, it suffices to plug $x = y = 0$ into the original equation to find that
$$
f(0) = f(0) + f(0) + 0
$$
which means that we must have $D = f(0) = 0$.  Thus, the (once-differentiable) solutions to your equation will all the form
$$
f(x) = \frac 12 x^2 + Cx
$$
for some real number $C$.

Comment: This is great, but are we assuming too much when we say $f'(0)$ is a constant? Also from there I am not really seeing the steps where you can deduce that the function takes the quadratic form $\frac{1}{2} x^2+Cx+D$. Sorry to be so difficult.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind we are not. The fundamental approach to this question is "if $f$ is an infinitely differentiable function satisfying the equation, then what can we say about $f$"?  We're given that $f$ is a function and that $f'$ is also a function.  It follows that $f'(0)$ is a number, i.e. a constant.

Comment: Yes ok sorry since the function is evaluated at a certain point.

Comment: Regarding your second question: we have a differential equation, which is 
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = x + C.
$$
By integrating both sides, we obtain its solution.

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask questions; these answers are being written mostly for your benefit after all.  If you find that an answer you got is difficult to understand and the answerer can't explain it, remember that you can ask a new question regarding your specific difficulty with the answer.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. In our class we have not introduced integration, however we can ask the question: differentiating which function will yield $x$ as the derivative. Likewise differentiating which function will yield a constant C as the derivative. Great I get it.

Answer (score 2):

You have proven that is a solution, but not that is the only one.

Firstly, if $x=y=0$, you find $f(0)=0$.

Suppose now $x,y\neq0$. Then, dividing by $x$ you get
$$\frac{f(x+y)-f(y)}{x}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}+y$$

Taking the limit for $x\to0$, you get the derivatives at $0$ and $y$:
$$f'(y)=f'(0)+y$$

Rearrange, divide by $y$ and get the limit for $y\to 0$:
$$f"(0)=1$$

Hence, by double integration you get (use $f(0)=0$
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+ax$$
with $a\in\mathbb R$.

These are all the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Placing $x=1$ and $y=0$ yields: $f(1)=f(1)+f(0) \Rightarrow f(0)=0$
2. Placing $y=-x$ yields $f(x)+f(-x) = x^2$

Comment: But $f(x)+f(-x)=f(x-x)=f(0)$?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind no, why? Has $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ that characteristic?

Comment: hmmm I guess not because of the $x^2$...